# Pre VM Deployment checks in ansible

Tags: windows, ansible, vcenter

I have been trying for the past days to make a playbook to check for some things before ansible starts creating a new windows VM, I'm a junior engineer and just starting on the path of Ansible

I figured out the ping part but what I really want to know is if there's some way to check if the computer name is already registered in Active Directory and if it is the workflow should stop.

I am not sure if win_domain_computer can also just check.

Thanks

Comment: `Create, read, update and delete computers in Active Directory` <= doc seems quite clear about it. See also the Ansible task level option `check_mode`

Answer (score 0):

I think a powershell request is a way to do that.

In my playbook, we don't check name in Active Directory, but we check dns record
with a task, something similar with get-adcomputer should be ok.

Task dns example :

```yml
- block:
  - name: Check dns record
    win_shell: Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName DNSSERVER -Name "{{ SERVERNAME }}" -ZoneName DNSZONE -RRType "A" -ErrorAction Ignore | select -ExpandProperty RecordData | select -ExpandProperty IPv4Address | select -Property IPAddressToString -ExpandProperty IPAddressToString
    register: reg_dnscheck
    changed_when: reg_dnscheck.rc == 1
    failed_when: reg_dnscheck.rc > 1
```